# I'm getting an error when trying to open a website url with Python 3.1, urllib & json: operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: python, json, urllib

I'm getting an error when trying to open a website url with Python 3.1, urllib & json

urllib.error.URLError:

Here's the code.  The first website loads fine.  The second one

```
import json
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import util

# This one works fine
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org/')
html = response.read()
print(html)

# parms - CSV filename, company, ....

p_filename = "c:\\temp\\test.csv"

jg_token = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
jg_proto = "https://"
jg_webst = "www.jigsaw.com/rest/"

jg_cmd_searchContact = "searchContact.json"

jg_key_companyName = "companyName"
jg_key_levels      = "levels"
jg_key_departments = "departments"

jg_args = {
        "token":jg_token,
        jg_key_companyName: "Technical Innovations",
        jg_key_departments: "HR"
        }

jg_url = jg_proto + jg_webst + jg_cmd_searchContact + "?" + urllib.parse.urlencode(jg_args)

    # This one generates teh error
result = json.load(urllib.request.urlopen(jg_url))
```

urllib.error.URLError:

File "c:\dev\xdev\PyJigsaw\searchContact.py", line 46, in 
  result = json.load(urllib.request.urlopen(jg_url))

File "c:\dev\tdev\Python31\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 121, in urlopen
  return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)

File "c:\dev\tdev\Python31\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 349, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)

File "c:\dev\tdev\Python31\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 367, in _open
  '_open', req)

File "c:\dev\tdev\Python31\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 327, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)

File "c:\dev\tdev\Python31\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 1098, in https_open
  return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req)

File "c:\dev\tdev\Python31\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 1075, in do_open
  raise URLError(err)

Answer (score 1):

Please edit the title and tags and maybe even the question body:
This has nothing to do with JSON and everything to do with Windows. It's also at a lower level than urllib. (Probably in the SSL code.) Distilled:

Both of the following approaches fail on Python 3.1.2 for Vista, but work fine on Linux (Python 3.1.3)

```
print( HTTPSConnection(hostname).request('GET',url).getresponse().read() )
print( urllib.request.urlopen('https://'+hostname+url).read() )
```

Change them to not use SSL, and then they work fine on Windows:

```
print( HTTPConnection(hostname).request('GET',url).getresponse().read() )
print( urllib.request.urlopen('http://'+hostname+url).read() )
```

Comment: Also, @Sabrown , try the above and see if you get the exact same error as I do:
`File "C:\ProgramFiles\Python31\lib\ssl.py", line 236, in sendall
    return socket.sendall(self, data, flags)
socket.error: [Errno 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket`

Answer (score 1):

On Vista, I just upgraded from Python 3.1.2 to Python 3.2 and this is no longer a problem.
The following now works just fine:

`print( urllib.request.urlopen('https://'+hostname+url).read() )`